# Why did desk boards split apart?

Tags: wood-movement, moisture

I ordered this reclaimed wood desk a few months back, and at first it looked pretty good. However, as a few weeks went by, I noticed the glue holding the boards together started to fail in many places, as well as a gnarly 10 inch crack growing on the side. From my initial research, this just seems like a moisture issue, but I would expect the boards to already be dried in a kiln or some type of process. Note, the desk was created in hot humid climate and was shipped to the NY Hudson Valley area. I also have forced air heating in the house. I contacted the company and they're not sure why this happened. My question is why did this happen? Is this just bad luck or the result of a manufacturing defect?

[image: angle]
[image: split]
[image: under desk]

Comment: Just a guess but I would say it is unlikely that it is  reclaimed wood. It does not look like old wood and if it  truly is old wood it would have done all its splitting  long ago.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Thank you for the insight. All I know is the desk was advertised as reclaimed wood.

Comment: The table constrained wood movement. This is 99% of the time the problem with stuff built along non-traditional lines (I'm looking at you Ana White).

Comment: "I contacted the company and they're not sure why this happened" Which indicates they're either hopelessly incompetent or lying. Given the way they built this thing, you can take it as a given the first is the case, but the second may also be true!

Comment: @AlaskaMan, wood continues to move indefinitely. Even wood *centuries* old (not exaggerating) if you constrain natural expansion and contraction with, for example, cross battens as here, you can get catastrophic crack formation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What general considerations do I need to take into account for wood movement?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/908/what-general-considerations-do-i-need-to-take-into-account-for-wood-movement) And more directly relevant information in this one, [Stabilizer for softwood tabletop that bows](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2439/stabilizer-for-softwood-tabletop-that-bows/2441#2441)

Comment: You see this a lot in factory made export furniture from places in Asia. For decades now, the "Pier 1" aesthetic has meant lots of cool looking stuff that looks great at first, but quickly falls apart because, well, it's more for show than for go. Carpentry is an art and a craft, and we ignore the second part at our peril.